# How does one configure DataGrip to connect to Redshift with SSL?

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I am able to connect to Redshift with SSL through SQLWorkbench with the latest driver. When I try to connect using DataGrip and select "Use SSL" with the latest driver, there is a failure.

Has anyone had issues with this? I have also tried adding query parameters to the URL after searching through other posts

`?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by removing all other query parameters and embedding the password into the URL string using `?PWD=<password>`. Each time I used the password box in the form and clicked "Apply", it would not save the password I entered. This was not an issue with other connections.

As a side note, this works whether I check "Use SSL" or not.

Comment: Do you use URL only mode or default?

Comment: @moscas At first, I used default, then used URL only. Each time, I tried entering the password in the form, then tried in the URL.